# How can I stream music over firefly media server to my ipod or iphone?

Tags: itunes, iphone, ipod

I just installed firefly media server on my debian server and am interested in not only streaming to computers around my house but also to my iphone and ipod touch.  Both have wifi access so I suppose I just need an app that can accept firefly streamed music?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found an app for this: [Simple DAAP Client](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simple-daap-client/id369605270?mt=8)